# Calling variables between JQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS, trying to build a game based around switching a set of tiles back and forth between two players.

One is function intended to switch turns between two players. Another changes the tiles' color, using the turn variable to determine which color to switch to.

I don't think either is working.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f5mEY/3

```
var currentPlayer;
var playerOne;
var playerTwo;
var turnCounter = 0;

//this function is intended to iterate between the two players when a player completes their turn by hitting submit
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        turnCounter += 1;
        if (turnCounter%2 === 0) {
            currentPlayer = playerOne;
        }
        else {
            currentPlayer = playerTwo;
        }
    });
});

//and this should turn the unplayed tiles to the correct player's color when they are clicked
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.unplayedTile').click(function() {
        if (currentPlayer === playerOne) {
            $(this).toggleClass('unplayedTile playerOneTile');
        }
        else {
            $(this).toggleClass('unplayedTile playerTwoTile');
        }
    });
});
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jsFiddle, the variables `playerOne` and `playerTwo` never get anything assigned to them so therefore they are both `undefined`.  If they have the same value, then you can't tell the difference between them in your `if` statements.

I don't know exactly how you intended to use those variables, but if you just assign them some initial value that is different between them, then your comparisons for who is the current player should start working.

```
var playerOne = 1;
var playerTwo = 2;
var currentPlayer = playerOne;
```

P.S. If you're trying to actually use the jsFiddle, you have to select the jQuery lib in the left hand panel so jQuery is available.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't get it working this way. I *think* that setting a value for the p1/p2 variables made it call that value in the comparisons. But I removed those vars & it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initiate `playerOne` and `playerTwo` with something that can be compared. Currently, `playerOne` and `playerTwo` are `undefined` which makes `currentPlayer === playerOne` always true

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not assigning any values to the player constants.

```
var currentPlayer = 1;
var playerOne = 1;
var playerTwo = 2;
var turnCounter = 0;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nQ6h3/)

Here the initial values are set so that currentPlayer will be the playerOne

Note: Also in the fiddle jQuery was not included